# Failed to send an SMS using a real device

Tags: android, sms

Failed to send sms in **using real device**. No Error Message. I allowed permission in the manifest file and imported the necessary classes, but still can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sendMessage(contact,message);

    private void sendMessage(String contact, String message)
{
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    try {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact, null , message , null , null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function..

sendMySMS(personalPhone,message);

```
 private void sendMySMS(String personalPhone, String messege)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(messege);
    for (String msg : messages)
    {
        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
        sms.sendTextMessage(personalPhone, null, msg, sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
    }
}
```

Add Permissions...

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a real device with Android 6.0(API 23) or higher, you must request permission at runtime.

SEND_SMS permission is classified as a dangerous permission.

So, before run sms send logic, you must ask user if allow the sending of messages.

To do that, first need to add this in your activity

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS); 
    }
```

Then you will check if the user has granted permissions adding this override method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // PERMISSION GRANTED
                // Now you can send sms
            } else {
                // PERMISSION DENIED
                // You should disable send sms feature
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```